# Memory Leak Suspicion

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks

I have a daemon(C program) running on my system.
A lot of other libraries gets attached to this daemon when the daemon is started.

There is an another user process which when run uses this daemon for its operation.

The problem is after the user process completes its operation when I see the output of top command for that daemon I see "RES" memory increased in MBs.
The %mem decreases to its previous level which was before I ran the process.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S   %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND          
 7456 root      20   0 73946  34m 3543 S      0  0.3  14:28.96 test_daemon
```

Does this increase in RES value signals memory leak?

Comment: increase in RES does not necessarily mean memory leak, loading dynamic library might be causing it.

Comment: You can check it with something like `valgrind`

Comment: thanks all for the reply.
But this increase in RES value is not fixed.
Sometimes it goes beyond 100 MB.
What I think is that if it is due to shared libraries loading then should not memory increase be limited to some value or fixed.
Anyway if there is some memory allocation in any libraries then it will increase in memory consumption of this daemon.
Am I correct?

Comment: Run valgrind and all your questions will be answered, instead of speculation on what *might* be happening by simply looking at top.

Comment: I checked in valgrind and it reports some 0.5 MB of leakage and this does not coincide with RES value of 34MB.
So I guess the 34 MB seen in RES may not be leakage.
Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, and probably no.  The only way to be sure that your code is memory leak free however is to run it with something like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org/).  Why use top when you can use an actual memory debugger and be sure?